# How to fix 'MSBUILD : error MSB1011' on my dockerfile?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, msbuild, dockerfile

I'm setting up the dockerfile follows this [example](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile). I'm stuck at the command as below.

**My project does not contain the csproj file initially.**

## Console

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  101.6MB
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
 ---> 161680d5c6b2
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c72d80e3abed
Step 3/10 : COPY *.sln .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 06bbfc478b4c
Step 4/10 : COPY *.config ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f2ebd7396f5a
Step 5/10 : RUN nuget restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3e33c0d2590
Step 6/10 : COPY . ./
 ---> fc8fe6acd4a3
Step 7/10 : RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release
 ---> Running in fe213a4b69d5

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.32702+c4012a063 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; msbuild /p:Configuration=Release' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I had run it on local by building the solution and using the IIS express which it ran smoothly, but my dockerfile is not. Below is my dockerfile that contains some instructions.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
# COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
COPY *.config ./
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . ./
# WORKDIR /app
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app ./
```

## Project Structure

```
/aspnetapp
├── *.aspx
├── *.aspx.cs
├── App_Code
├── App_Data
├── Documents
├── *.master
├── *.master.cs
├── Scripts
├── Styles
├── Templates
├── *.sln
├── assetinfo.json
├── bin
├── dockerfile
├── images
├── js
├── media
├── packages
├── package.config
├── web.config
└── *.publishproj
```

Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple projects and/or solutions that may be eligible to be built in the working directory you're in. When this is the case, you can provide the name of the solution to be built directly in your dockerfile.

```
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release mySolution.sln
```

or

```
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release myProject.csproj
```

Either of these should help get you through the build, or at least to the next issue you may be facing.